# Pandas Merge pd.read_csv - Inconsistent data return

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, merge

My issue is that I can merge the data but only from a certain dataset. The goal is to merge data for a customer outage map with an ISP. I've edited the data to be generic for demo purposes.

df1 is the customer data from the billing system with Name, address, etc.

df2 is the equipment data from the electronics with the ONT SN and ONT status

df2_Sub is a subset of data taken from df2, this data will populate the "ifOper" column though the full dataset of df2 will leave "ifOper" blank.

Here is how each data set looks

[df1 dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAM2Y.png)

[df2 dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geF2D.png)

If I comment out df2 and use df2_Sub I get this:

[df2_Sub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK0l9.png)

Otherwise i use the larger dataset and it adds the "ifOper" column but no data.

Same happens with a "left" join on either dataset, I get the column but no data.

merge.dtypes returns the same type for both datasets as well.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("CX_Info.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("ONT_Status.csv")
#df2_Sub = pd.read_csv("Subset_ONT_Status.csv")


#merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner", on="ONT")
#merge.sort_values(by=['ONT'], inplace=True)

merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='ONT', right_on='ONT', how='left')

merge.reset_index(drop=True)
merge.reindex(axis = 0)

print(merge)
merge.to_csv('new_df.csv', index=False)
```

Added pd.to_dict() for reference

df1

```
{
'ONT': 'ADTN20074B3C', 
'SERV_TYPE': 'RESIDENTIAL INTERNET                              ', 'ACCOUNT STATUS': 'CONNECTED', 
'MBRSEP': 555555, 
'NAME': 'CUSTOMER ONE               ', 
'SVC_ADDRESS': '223 COUNTY HWY 598          ', 
'CITY': 'JACKSON', 
'COUNTY': 'JEFFERSON                                            ', 'STATE': 'MS                                                ', 'ZIP': 55555, 
'PLANNAME': 'RESIDENTIAL 1 GIG', 
'LATITUDE': 23.97445452, 
'LONGITUDE': -54.774681}


df2
247: {'ONT': 'ADTN200052C3', 'ifOper': 'up'}, 248: {'ONT': 'ADTN19092222', 'ifOper': 'up'}, 249: {'ONT': 'ADTN18204592', 'ifOper': 'down'}

df2_sub

{0: {'ONT': 'ADTN19161620', 'ifOper': 'up'}, 1: {'ONT': 'ADTN19161397', 'ifOper': 'up'}, 2: {'ONT': 'ADTN19161350', 'ifOper': 'down'}, 3: {'ONT': 'ADTN19161216', 'ifOper': 'up'}, 4: {'ONT': 'ADTN185011e9', 'ifOper': 'up'}, 5: {'ONT': 'ADTN185011cc', 'ifOper': 'down'}
```

Comment: Hello, instead of pictures, could you please show a `pd.to_dict()` for each of the dataframes? Thanks.

Comment: I would but this set is 13,000 rows and 14 columns with personal information.
df2 is around 1,600 rows.

Comment: Just for the first few rows that are already in your images. So we can access easier.

Comment: I can do that, stand by

Comment: Here is the last lines of the full df2:

247: {'ONT': 'ADTN200052C3', 'ifOper': 'up'}, 
248: {'ONT': 'ADTN19092222', 'ifOper': 'up'}, 
249: {'ONT': 'ADTN18204592', 'ifOper': 'down'}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was created because of a duplicate data frame in one of my merge statements. After removing the duplicate and adding the correct df the desired result was attained.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment for the time being, can delete later.

I tried running the following code but I was unable to reproduce any of the dataframes from the images. The last one errs. Please ensure that you can reverse with `from_dict` to generate exactly the data you want us to use.

```py
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({247: {'ONT': 'ADTN200052C3', 'ifOper': 'up'}, 248: {'ONT': 'ADTN19092222', 'ifOper': 'up'}, 249: {'ONT': 'ADTN18204592', 'ifOper': 'down'}, })
df2_sub = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({0: {'ONT': 'ADTN19161620', 'ifOper': 'up'}, 1: {'ONT': 'ADTN19161397', 'ifOper': 'up'}, 2: {'ONT': 'ADTN19161350', 'ifOper': 'down'}, 3: {'ONT': 'ADTN19161216', 'ifOper': 'up'}, 4: {'ONT': 'ADTN185011e9', 'ifOper': 'up'}, 5: {'ONT': 'ADTN185011cc', 'ifOper': 'down'}})

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'ONT': 'ADTN20074B3C',
'SERV_TYPE': 'RESIDENTIAL INTERNET',
'ACCOUNT STATUS': 'CONNECTED', 
'MBRSEP': 555555, 
'NAME': 'CUSTOMER ONE', 
'SVC_ADDRESS': '223 COUNTY HWY 598',
'CITY': 'JACKSON',
'COUNTY': 'JEFFERSON',
'STATE': 'MS',
'ZIP': 55555, 
'PLANNAME': 'RESIDENTIAL 1 GIG', 
'LATITUDE': 23.97445452, 
'LONGITUDE': -54.774681})
```